# how insert Initial value in yii2 ckeditor

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

```
        <?= 
            $form->field($model, 'template')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
                'options' => ['rows' => 100],
                'preset' => 'full',
                'value'=>'<p>Incercam sa editam</p>',
            ])->label(true)
        ?>
```

This is my code 
I need to set initial value in editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a value in your field template eg in  you controller/create

```
  public function actionCreate()
  {
      $model = new YourModel();


      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
      } else {
          $model->template ="your initila value ....... text "
          return $this->render('@common/views/antigone-contribuente/create', [
              'model' => $model,
          ]);
      }
  }
```

once you have assigne to youe $model->template the value you need  yuo should see this in your editor in view